# Read XML in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have googled for the last hour or so with no luck (I'd like to think I'm a great googler too!), so here I am.

I have an XML file that I'm using for my programs settings, it looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <store>
        <number>0323</number>
        <address>address</address>
        <phone>phone</phone>
    </store>

    <emailsettings>
        <emailfrom>emailfrom</emailfrom>
        <emailpass>pass</emailpass>
        <emailsubject>received</emailsubject>
        <smtpserver>smtp.gmail.com</smtpserver>
        <smtpport>587</smtpport>
        <enablessl>true</enablessl>
        <emailbody>package received</emailbody>
    </emailsettings>
    <dbconfig>
        <dbpath>path</dbpath>
    </dbconfig>
</config>
```

How can I use vb.net to get each element and return a specific value that I want? Per se, I'd like to return `<number>` (under `<store>`) in textbox1, and `<emailbody>` (under `<emailsettings>`) in textbox2.

Help pleaseeeeee! Thanks :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ah, a perfect example for showing off the powerful XML features of VB.NET with Framework 3.5:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim xml = XDocument.Load("config.xml")
    Console.WriteLine("Number: " & xml.<config>.<store>.<number>.Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Body: " & xml.<config>.<emailsettings>.<emailbody>.Value)
End Sub
```

yields:

```
Number: 0323
Body: package received
```

Comment: This is a great answer, WAY better than my serialization answer.  Your answer is what I was looking for on my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253900/generics-and-duck-typing-xml-in-net Please add this answer to my question and I will accept.

Comment: Splendid, but what if you have multiple number of another store as file could be one configurations file for multiple stores?

Comment: @AhmedNazmy: `For Each store in xml.<config>.<store>`. Then, inside the loop, access `store.<number>.Value`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Console app using the VB.Net XML Literal support.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim xElem = <config>
                       <store>
                           <number>0323</number>
                           <address>address</address>
                           <phone>phone</phone>
                       </store>

                       <emailsettings>
                           <emailfrom>emailfrom</emailfrom>
                           <emailpass>pass</emailpass>
                           <emailsubject>received</emailsubject>
                           <smtpserver>smtp.gmail.com</smtpserver>
                           <smtpport>587</smtpport>
                           <enablessl>true</enablessl>
                           <emailbody>package received</emailbody>
                       </emailsettings>
                       <dbconfig>
                           <dbpath>path</dbpath>
                       </dbconfig>
                   </config>

        Dim number = xElem.<store>.<number>.Value
        Dim emailbody = xElem.<emailsettings>.<emailbody>.Value

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number={0}", number))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("emailbody={0}", emailbody))
        Console.ReadLine()

        '--- What it'd look like if you loaded from a file using XDocument.Load
        Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load(New IO.StringReader(xElem.ToString))
        number = xDoc.Root.<store>.<number>.Value
        emailbody = xDoc.Root.<emailsettings>.<emailbody>.Value

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Number={0}", number))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("emailbody={0}", emailbody))
        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub

End Module
```

The results will be:

> ```
> Number=0323
> emailbody=package received
>
> Number=0323
> emailbody=package received
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML Serialization.  Create classes that represent your XML structure and use the XML Serialization Class to deserialize the data.  Once you have done that you can use the data in your application.

Below is a link to an example from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Comment: +1. I use this all the time when I have to read/write XML I have under control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with datasets and datatables, this is an easy way to do it:

```
Dim DS As New DataSet
DS.ReadXml("Data.xml")
```

DataSets can read any XML. I even use this to call rest-enabled XML services.