# Collect value from single xml attribute within element vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I've been trying to work out how to make this work for a few days now (I've ended up in the loop of viewing the same articles again because you've googled so many combinations of the question)

I've looked at [Read XML in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267405/read-xml-in-vb-net)
and [How to read an XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933333/how-to-read-an-xml-file) and [How to read XML elements in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581692/how-to-read-xml-elements-in-vb-net) and [Retrieve single attribute value from an xml doc element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432185/retrieve-single-attribute-value-from-an-xml-doc-element) of which the last one seemed to point me in the round about right direction, but upon running the code as specified by DWRoelands I receive "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" to the console output.

Please see below XML, I need to extract https://server/transfer/descriptor.ovf from the HREF attribute in the /Files/File/Link element and only for the File listed as descriptor.ovf (the second XML file I run this on has another File listed for a VMDK)

Thanks

XML Snippet:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VApp href="https://#####/api/vApp/vapp-##">
    <Link rel="down"/>
    <Description>Test vAPP</Description>
    <Tasks>
        <Task cancelRequested="false" >
            <Link rel="task:cancel" />
            <Progress>1</Progress>
            <Details/>
        </Task>
    </Tasks>
    <Files>
        <File bytesTransferred="0" size="-1" name="descriptor.ovf">
            <Link rel="upload:default" href="https://server/transfer/descriptor.ovf"/>
        </File>
    </Files>
    <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
</VApp>
```

Whole XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<VApp xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5" ovfDescriptorUploaded="false" deployed="false" status="0" name="Test vAPP" id="urn:vcloud:vapp:#####" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vApp+xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5 https://server/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd">
    <Link rel="down" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####/controlAccess/" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.controlAccess+xml"/>
    <Link rel="up" href="https://server/api/vdc/#####" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vdc+xml"/>
    <Link rel="down" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####/owner" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.owner+xml"/>
    <Link rel="down" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####/metadata" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.metadata+xml"/>
    <Link rel="ovf" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####/ovf" type="text/xml"/>
    <Link rel="down" href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####/productSections/" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.productSections+xml"/>
    <Description>Test vAPP</Description>
    <Tasks>
        <Task cancelRequested="false" expiryTime="2017-07-30T11:02:07.457+08:00" operation="Importing Virtual Application Test vAPP(#####)" operationName="vdcUploadOvfContents" serviceNamespace="com.vmware.vcloud" startTime="2017-05-01T11:02:07.457+08:00" status="running" name="task" id="urn:vcloud:task:######" href="https://server/api/task/####" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.task+xml">
            <Link rel="task:cancel" href="https://server/api/task/#####/action/cancel"/>
            <Owner href="https://server/api/vApp/vapp-#####" name="Test vAPP" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.vApp+xml"/>
            <User href="https://server/api/admin/user/####" name="#####" type="application/vnd.vmware.admin.user+xml"/>
            <Organization href="https://server/api/org/#####" name="#####" type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.org+xml"/>
            <Progress>1</Progress>
            <Details/>
        </Task>
    </Tasks>
    <Files>
        <File bytesTransferred="0" size="-1" name="descriptor.ovf">
            <Link rel="upload:default" href="https://server/transfer/#####/descriptor.ovf"/>
        </File>
    </Files>
    <DateCreated>2017-05-01T11:02:07.417+08:00</DateCreated>
    <Owner type="application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.owner+xml">
        <User href="https://server/api/admin/user/#####" name="#####" type="application/vnd.vmware.admin.user+xml"/>
    </Owner>
    <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
</VApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

First load your file, and if you use XElement you can use literals to test.

```
    'Dim yourpath As String = "your path here"
    Dim xe As XElement
    'to load from a file
    'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)

    'for testing
    xe = <VApp href="https://#####/api/vApp/vapp-##">
             <Link rel="down"/>
             <Description>Test vAPP</Description>
             <Tasks>
                 <Task cancelRequested="false">
                     <Link rel="task:cancel"/>
                     <Progress>1</Progress>
                     <Details/>
                 </Task>
             </Tasks>
             <Files>
                 <File bytesTransferred="0" size="-1" name="descriptor.ovf">
                     <Link rel="upload:default" href="https://server/transfer/descriptor.ovf"/>
                 </File>
             </Files>
             <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
         </VApp>


    ' to save file
    ' xe.Save(yourpath)
```

Now that it is loaded it is easy to select the element you want

**edited**

```
    Dim dovf As IEnumerable = (From el In xe...<Files>
                               Where el.<File>.@name = "descriptor.ovf"
                               Select el.<File>.<Link>.@href)

    For Each s As String In dovf
        Stop
    Next
```

based on the whole xml example from above I had to add this as the first line of the program

```
Imports <xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/v1.5">
```

Comment: Hi dbasnett, 

Thanks for the reply.

I've tested the code and it looks to do what I need, however when I substitute the example I provided earlier (cut down xml) with the whole XML, it fires blank lines to the console, when I write the dovf variable to the console.

I've updated the post to include the actual code (with sensitive information hashed out)

Are you able to point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Paste your xml as classes with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx). Make sure any xml arrays have multiple items so the schema gets generated correctly. Here is my result:

```vb
'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute([Namespace]:="", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class VApp

    Private linkField As VAppLink

    Private descriptionField As String

    Private tasksField() As VAppTask

    Private filesField() As VAppFile

    Private inMaintenanceModeField As Boolean

    Private hrefField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Link() As VAppLink
        Get
            Return Me.linkField
        End Get
        Set(value As VAppLink)
            Me.linkField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return Me.descriptionField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.descriptionField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Task", IsNullable:=False)> _
    Public Property Tasks() As VAppTask()
        Get
            Return Me.tasksField
        End Get
        Set(value As VAppTask())
            Me.tasksField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("File", IsNullable:=False)> _
    Public Property Files() As VAppFile()
        Get
            Return Me.filesField
        End Get
        Set(value As VAppFile())
            Me.filesField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property InMaintenanceMode() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.inMaintenanceModeField
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.inMaintenanceModeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property href() As String
        Get
            Return Me.hrefField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.hrefField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class VAppLink

    Private relField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property rel() As String
        Get
            Return Me.relField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.relField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class VAppTask

    Private linkField As VAppTaskLink

    Private progressField As Byte

    Private detailsField As Object

    Private cancelRequestedField As Boolean

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Link() As VAppTaskLink
        Get
            Return Me.linkField
        End Get
        Set(value As VAppTaskLink)
            Me.linkField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Progress() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.progressField
        End Get
        Set(value As Byte)
            Me.progressField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Details() As Object
        Get
            Return Me.detailsField
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            Me.detailsField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property cancelRequested() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.cancelRequestedField
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.cancelRequestedField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class VAppTaskLink

    Private relField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property rel() As String
        Get
            Return Me.relField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.relField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class VAppFile

    Private linkField As VAppFileLink

    Private bytesTransferredField As Byte

    Private sizeField As SByte

    Private nameField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    Public Property Link() As VAppFileLink
        Get
            Return Me.linkField
        End Get
        Set(value As VAppFileLink)
            Me.linkField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property bytesTransferred() As Byte
        Get
            Return Me.bytesTransferredField
        End Get
        Set(value As Byte)
            Me.bytesTransferredField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property size() As SByte
        Get
            Return Me.sizeField
        End Get
        Set(value As SByte)
            Me.sizeField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return Me.nameField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.nameField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'''<remarks/>
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType:=True)> _
Partial Public Class VAppFileLink

    Private relField As String

    Private hrefField As String

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property rel() As String
        Get
            Return Me.relField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.relField = value
        End Set
    End Property

    '''<remarks/>
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()> _
    Public Property href() As String
        Get
            Return Me.hrefField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.hrefField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then deserialize the xml to these classes. Use LINQ to find the only* element with `name = "descriptor.ovf"`. Add exception handling as needed.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim myVApp As VApp
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(VApp))
    Using sr As New StreamReader("XMLFile1.xml")
        myVApp = CType(serializer.Deserialize(sr), VApp)
    End Using
    Dim href = myVApp.Files.Single(Function(f) f.name = "descriptor.ovf").Link.href
    Console.WriteLine(href)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Output:

> https://server/transfer/descriptor.ovf

*You could use `Single`, `Where`, or `First` with the same predicate to return the only item, all items, or the first item with that name, respectively.